# where to add connection string of SQL server in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am having an ASP.NET page that is containing the textboxes namely username and password and a button named cmdlogin. I want  that when I enter the data in text boxes then that data should be saved into the database.

In SQL server of Visual studio, I have created table and even also have given the

```
INSERT INTO cmd_login VALUES(".......").
```

Now the problem is when I entered the data in textbooxes it is not saved in the database table. what can I do.

I have put my connection string into the class file. Do I need to put my connection string in the `web.config`?

my code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public class Db
{
    public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString =@"Data                 Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\talat\MyRealSacaProject\App_Data\SACALogin.mdf;Inte    grated Security=True;User Instance=True;";
        cn.Open();
        return cn;
    }
    public static void SaveAdmin(admin a)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = GetConnection();
        string sql = "INSERT INTO admin_login VALUES(@[User-Name],@Password)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[User-Name]",a.username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", a.password);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please Add your code here..

Comment: plz show your code to us ,,as well as your connection string as well

Answer (score 0):

try this simple code:

```
SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection(_connString);
_conn.Open();
SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand();
_cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
_cmd.Parameters.Clear();
_cmd.Connection = _conn;
_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [tablename] VALUE ([fieldvalue])"; //here your textbox    
int _execute = _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

bool _result = false;
if(_execute != 1)
    _result = true;

_conn.Close();
```

Comment: mine Code is
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public class Db
{
public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
{SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
cn.ConnectionString =@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\talat\MyRealSacaProject\App_Data\SACALogin.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;";
cn.Open();
return cn;}
public static void SaveAdmin(admin a)
{SqlConnection cn = GetConnection();
string sql="INSERT INTO admin_login VALUES(@[User-Name])";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[User-Name]",a.username);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 cn.Close();}}

Answer (score 0):

chnage your code as given below, it will work

```
public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    string ConString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\talat\MyRealSacaProject\App_Data\SACALogin.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConString);

    cn.Open();
    return cn;
}
```

Comment: it is giving me an error that ConString doesn't eist in the current context ..... ????

Answer (score 0):

try this change from your code :

```
public static void SaveAdmin(admin a)
{
    SqlConnection cn = GetConnection();
    string sql = "INSERT INTO admin_login VALUES('" + a.username + "','" + a.Password + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: It is not helping me .... I am still not able to insert the values... into the Database table

Comment: Add your connection string into web,config and then access it using ConfigurationManager class.

Comment: change in your GetConnection(); ConnString = "Server=[your server ip]\[instance]; UID=[username]; PWD=[password]; Database=[databasename];" example : ConnString = "Server=202.129.191.x\production; UID=userems; PWD=userems.123; Database=EMS;"